# How to connect from symfony to SQL Azure database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, odbc, symfony-1.4, azure-sql-database

I'm having problems connecting Symfony 1.4 with a SQL Azure database.

How to configure databases.yml?

I tried:

```
#databases.yml
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
      #option1
      dsn: sqlsrv:server=tcp:c0yb8ju4aa.database.windows.net,1433;Database=neurodb

      #option2
      dsn: odbc:DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=c0yb8ju4aa.database.windows.net;Database=neurodb

      #option3
      dsn: odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=tcp:c0yb8ju4aa.database.windows.net,1433;Database=neurodb;Uid=neurodb@c0yb8ju4aa;Pwd=mypass;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;

      username: neurodb@c0yb8ju4aa
      password: mypass
```

Option1 says:

```
Unknown driver sqlsrv
```

Option2 and Option3 says:

```
Couldn't locate driver named odbc
```

Symfony web app is located in an "Azure Website"

Which is the correct way to connect my web app to the database?

Comment: Have you tried `mssql`? Doctrine 1.2 does not have `sqlsrv` driver. It is described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/introduction-to-connections.html#providing-the-dsn) how to write the dsn. Or you can use [sfPropelORMPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPropelORMPlugin) with [sqlsrv](http://propelorm.org/cookbook/using-mssql-server.html).

Comment: @1ed; I just tried it with: **dsn:       mssql:server=tcp:c0yb8ju4aa.database.windows.net,1433;Database=neurodb**. Shows: Couldn't locate driver mssql. Any ideas?

Comment: no more sorry... I don't know azure but somehow you should install [pdo driver extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) for php and use that in the dsn.

Comment: At the end, i used clearDB MySQL databases (from azure management dashboard), I cant get SQL azure database to work with symfony.